# Self-hosting and Apache virtual host on a Synology NAS: any security risk?

Tags: web-hosting, security, virtualhost, vhost

I have a Synology NAS running an Apache web server with several Virtual Hosts. Currently, each vhost is associated with a different port, and my router is pointing on them individually. I also have a static IP address.

Now, let's say I want to buy a couple of domain names, and make them point on my vhosts.

**What I plan to do is:**

1. On my domain names, point each A field on my IP address
2. On my router, forward WAN port 80 to NAS port 8099 (or anything else, to not interfere with the others ports used by the NAS)
3. Change my vhosts configuration to listen the 8099 port and redirect the user to the right website with the domain name.
4. Same idea for the WAN port 443.

**My question is:**
I am planning to do it right?
And assuming the websites are correctly secured (I want to make public 2 websites: 1 Wordpress (obviously up to date) and 1 static (pages generated my PHP, no user interaction or upload)). Are there any security issues (eg. a risk of accessing private files on the NAS or accessing other services on other ports than 8099)?

Comment: When you say "redirect the user to the right website" do you mean that you are planning to reverse proxy the site from the correct port on your NAS?

Comment: I actually plan to configure my vhosts with the same port (in my example, 8099), it should serve the good website according the the domain name, right?

Comment: The big issue you have with using any NAS is that you are at the mercy of the manufacture to update their software, especially if the item becomes end of line and then the updates become fewer and fewer. Unless your device allows unrestricted management of the operating system and the services without having to wait for Firmware updates then I recommend that you avoid using it period. These devices are notorious for backdoor hacks and zero days.

Comment: And what about "hiding" the webserver in a chrooted environment? I can do it on my NAS.

Comment: Personally I use Hardkernel ODROID XU4 with Cloudshell that comes with a unrestricted Ubuntu with no need for firmwares. Only uses a few watts and is very powerful. Synology does however have a better security reputable unlike the WD and Buffalo but still...

Comment: `"hiding" the webserver in a chrooted environment` Yes you should or just disable SSH from the outside and correctly setup CHMOD. Also if you have personal files, they should also be chmod on another user, but I imagine that comes as standard within the dashboard of your NAS.

Comment: SSH is already enabled from inside only. When I need it from outside, I'm using a VPN to connect to my network. The web files are indeed on another user and group than my personal files. I'll check the chmod for the web files but I think it's ok.